# How can I make Vim recognise ordinal numbers (1st, 2nd) as valid spellings?

Tags: spell-checking

If I `set spell`, Vim seems to only recognise some ordinal numbers: `1st`, `2nd`, etc. are fine, but anything from `10th` to `20th` is apparently misspelled. Then `21st`, `22nd` and `23rd` are fine, but then they're all misspellings until `31st`...

[image: image as described above]

I'm using Vim 8.1.290.

Why is Vim so inconsistent here, and how can I fix it (ideally without adding `th` to my spellfile)?

Comment: I don't think 21-23, 31-33 are actually considered correct spellings. Put "st", "nd" or "rd" after any number and it's no longer flagged. Probably 1 through 9 are in the dictionary and that's it. Did you try adding any of the others to the dictionary?

Comment: 31st (for instance) actually is correct though.  You say "thirty-first" not "thirty-oneth".

Comment: @DopeGhoti You mean all this time that I've been saying "thirty-oneth" and "twenty-three'nd" I've been wrong? :P What I actually meant was that *Vim* doesn't consider them correct (or incorrect) spellings...`31st` and `31nd` are treated equally.

Answer (score 1):

This is an `aspell` problem; not a `vim` problem.  `aspell` itself has these deficiencies.  You need simply to add the missing ordinal numbers to the dictionary.

```
$ echo "1st 21st 31st 5th 25th 35th" | aspell -a
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707)
*
*
*
& th 50 15: Th, Thu, the, tho, thy, THC, Rh, HT, ht, H, T, h, t, nth, Ch, OH, TA, Ta, Te, Ti, Tu, Ty, ah, ch, eh, oh, pH, sh, ta, ti, to, uh, DH, NH, TB, TD, TM, TN, TV, TX, Tb, Tc, Tl, Tm, tb, tn, tr, ts, Th's, T's
& th 50 20: Th, Thu, the, tho, thy, THC, Rh, HT, ht, H, T, h, t, nth, Ch, OH, TA, Ta, Te, Ti, Tu, Ty, ah, ch, eh, oh, pH, sh, ta, ti, to, uh, DH, NH, TB, TD, TM, TN, TV, TX, Tb, Tc, Tl, Tm, tb, tn, tr, ts, Th's, T's
& th 50 25: Th, Thu, the, tho, thy, THC, Rh, HT, ht, H, T, h, t, nth, Ch, OH, TA, Ta, Te, Ti, Tu, Ty, ah, ch, eh, oh, pH, sh, ta, ti, to, uh, DH, NH, TB, TD, TM, TN, TV, TX, Tb, Tc, Tl, Tm, tb, tn, tr, ts, Th's, T's
```